# How to get sticky notes in select statement?

Tags: php

i have to put sticky notes for select statement below but didn't appear also because i want to edit the category[men and women]. whenever i want to edit women or men.. it always appear men, it cannot get the category type i saved before (women).

```
<p>Category </td>
<td>:
    <select id="category_name" name="category_name" value="<?php echo  
        $category_name=$_GET['category_name'] ?>">
<?php
  include('connect.php');
  $query="SELECT category_name FROM category";
  $result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Query to get data from category failed:    
".mysql_error());
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $category=$row["category_name"];
    echo "<option>$category</option>";
  } 
?>
```

Comment: Can you show your select box html through an screenshot by using firbug and lightshot?

Comment: i don't have. i select this category from database.

Comment: you can not edit women or men its illegal  , please dont use mysql_* function they are depricated

Comment: Can we see your form - is the post handled by the same page? Try a `print_r($_POST); exit();` when a post is detected, and see what it contains.

Comment: at my college they are still using mysql_ function and im newby in php.

Comment: where to put print_r($_POST); exit(); ?

Answer (score 1):

To select the good option you have to add the attribute "selected" to the option you want to be selected.

Selects element don't have a "value" attribute.
It's the option that have the selected attribute.

So to have a select with women selected, you should do this :

```
<select name='select_gender'>
  <option value='man'>Man</option>
  <option value='woman' selected>Woman</option>
</select>
```

On a side note, you never want to echo `$_GET` data as is.
It's a security issue, check "XSS" and "htmlentities()"

Comment: Good spot. Might need a `name` attribute in the outer tag, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Product Name </td><td>:</td><td> <input name="prod_name" type="text"  
class="ed" id="name"></p>
<p>Category </td><td>:
<select id="category_name" name="category_name" class="ed">
<?php include('connect.php');

$query="SELECT category_name FROM category";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Query to get data from category 
failed: ".mysql_error());
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$category=$row["category_name"];
echo "<option> $category </option>";
}  ?>
</select></p>
<p>Brand</td><td>:
<select id="brand_name" name="brand_name" class="ed">
<?php
include('connect.php');
$query="SELECT brand_name FROM brand";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Query to get data from category failed: 
".mysql_error());
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$brand=$row["brand_name"];
echo "<option>  $brand </option>";
} ?>
</select></p>
<p>Color </td><td>:</td><td> <input name="prod_color" type="text" class="ed" 
id="color"></p>
<p> Description</td><td>:</td><td><input name="prod_description" type="text"  
id="desc" class="ed"/><br /> </p>
<p>Price </td><td>:</td><td> <input name="prod_price" type="text" class="ed"  
id="price"></p>
Product Image: <br /><input type="file" name="image" class="ed"><br />
```